# How to correctly uninstall and remove something and built from source and installed?

Tags: uninstall, compiling, cmake

I built openCV3 from source and installed it on my machine. I now want to remove it. Could someone tell me what the *correct* way of doing this is?

```
      ~/Downloads/opencv-3.2.0$ ls
      3rdparty  apps  build  cmake  CMakeLists.txt  CONTRIBUTING.md  data  doc  include  LICENSE  modules  platforms  README.md  samples

      ~/Downloads/opencv-3.2.0/build$ ls
      3rdparty               CMakeVars.txt            doc                   opencv2                     share
      apps                   CPackConfig.cmake        include               OpenCVConfig.cmake          test-reports
      bin                    CPackSourceConfig.cmake  install_manifest.txt  OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  text_config.hpp
      CMakeCache.txt         CTestTestfile.cmake      junk                  opencv_lapack.h             unix-install
      CMakeFiles             custom_hal.hpp           lib                   OpenCVModules.cmake         version_string.tmp
      cmake_install.cmake    cvconfig.h               Makefile              opencv_tests_config.hpp
      cmake_uninstall.cmake  data                     modules               samples
```

Thanks!

Comment: How did you go about installing it?

Comment: @AndroidDev mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -D someOptions & make & sudo make install

Comment: @AndroidDev what do you think in this case?  xargs rm < install_manifest.txt?

Comment: Yeah arrowd's answer seems OK to me. You may need to prefix it with `sudo` though.

Comment: Most applications have the uninstalling option configured as well so you can simply run `make uninstall`. Try that and let me know.

Comment: @Adonist too late :) Arrowd's answer worked like a charm

Comment: No problem, just remember that this is an option in the future. Might come in hand at some point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `xargs rm < install_manifest.txt` from the build folder to delete all files installed by `make install`. Then delete your build and source directory.

Comment: what about all the files generated by make (not sudo make install)? I guess those will still be on the system because you are telling that it will delete the files installed by sudo make install

Comment: `> Then delete your build and source directory.` Former would remove files generated both by `make` and `cmake`.